# macOS requesting permissions for network read+write

Tags: macos, go, networking, permissions, sudo

I am writing a service/module in Go for a bigger system and I'm having trouble with permissions on macOS. I am hoping anyone here has any experience with this.

This module is using network interfaces in macOS (read+write), and therefore needs admin/root permissions. The module is also in the form of a process which will communicate with parent process through stdio. Since it needs root permissions, I have tried wrapping it in AppleScript: `do shell script [...] with administrator privileges`, but osascripts does not return the output in real time, instead it returns the stdio output when process has exited. I need the stdio output in real-time, and it is annoying to write the password every time the module is started.

So that leaves me with the question of how I can request permissions for network control in Go. Like the popup you see on some programs "wants to use your microphone", only with network permissions. Is this possible?

If not, how can I solve this issue of needing root permission for a real-time module in macOS?

Answer (score 0):

I found a viable solution; launching the script with sudo -S , and asking the user for root password through my own GUI service. As long as the root password isn't stored anywhere, it should be fine security-wise.